# Where can I find a good ASP.NET MVC sample?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been using Castle MonoRail for the last two years, but in a new job I am going to be the one to bring in ASP.NET MVC with me.

I understand the basics of views, actions and the like. 
I just need a good sample for someone with MVC experience. 
Any good links besides Scott's Northwind traders sample?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[CodeCampServer](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/) - Built with ASP.NET MVC, pretty light and small project.  No cruft at all.

@lomaxx - Just FYI, most of what Troy Goode wrote is now part of [ASP.NET MVC as of Preview 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

[Rob Conery's MVC Storefront project](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/) is a good from-the-ground-up step-by-step series on how to put up an ASP.NET MVC site.

Comment: I found Rob Conery's MVC Storefront to be terrible.  He will discuss the concepts, but when it gets to implementation (Microsoft Ajax controls, Lazy Loading) his demos are lacking.  Also the Source Code doesn't match the videos.

Comment: It looks like the source code hasn't been updated since 10/29/08. http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18861

Comment: Jim, I guess that's what you call link rot. You do see that the answer provided was back in August of 2008

Answer (score 4):

Check out Billy McCafferty's [S#arp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) project for a great ASP.NET MVC starter project filled with best practices.

If you want something a little simpler, I threw together a rudimentary version of the S#arp Architecture project, called [Blunt Architecturehere](http://code.google.com/p/bluntarchitecture/).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for something like [Kigg - Building a Digg Clone with ASP.NET MVC](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/KiggBuildingADiggCloneWithASPNETMVC1.aspx).

Or maybe Jeff and the team are willing to provide you the souce code for SO... :P

Answer (score 2):

What about the [MVC Membership application](http://www.squaredroot.com/post/2008/04/MVC-Membership-Starter-Kit.aspx) that Troy Goode wrote. I'm not sure what Preview he wrote it in but it could be worth a look.

Also, if you want to go right from the beginning, scott gu has a [great series of posts on MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx)

Finally, I haven't personally taken a look at this code, but I noticed the [MVCSample app](http://www.codeplex.com/mvcsamples) on codeplex and bookmarked it for future reference, but I'm not sure of the quality.

Edit: he has an [updated version](http://www.squaredroot.com/post/2008/04/MVC-Membership-Starter-Kit-1-2.aspx) as well

Comment: I found these very frustrating.  In particular, I found Scoutt Gu's posts are out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [WineCellarManagerOnASPNETMVC](http://bartreyserhove.blogspot.com/2008/11/aspnet-mvc-and-rhino-tools-sample.html). It is a good sample project that is done using ASP.NET MVC and Rhino Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of these:

- [MVCPress/Blog](http://www.codeplex.com/mvcpress)
- [CarTrackr](http://www.codeplex.com/CarTrackr/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18356)
- [HaackOverflow](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/07/haackoverflow-vs-stackoverflow.aspx) by Phil Haack
- [Forums](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/09/05/asp-net-mvc-application-building-forums-1-create-the-perfect-application.aspx) by Stephen Walther

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [TheBeerHouse MVC Edition](http://www.codeplex.com/TheBeerHouse/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx). Its a full featured website that uses the latest MVC Framework RC1, SQL Server 2008, LINQ to SQL, jQuery, and much more. There is even an Ecommerce piece integrated into it!