# What ASP.NET MVC sample projects exist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The only sample ASP.NET MVC projects I know about are the following from http://asp.net/mvc.  Are there others?

- [Nerddinner.com](http://www.codeplex.com/nerddinner)
- [ProDinner](http://prodinner.codeplex.com)
- [Stephen Walther's Contact Manager](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-26-cs.aspx)
- [Rob Conery's MVC Storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/)
- [CodeCampServer](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/)
- [Suteki Shop E-Commerce Application](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/)
- [Stephen Walther's Movie Database](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-395.aspx)

Comment: Here's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408/where-can-i-find-a-good-asp-net-mvc-sample) already asked trying to find a good ASP.NET MVC sample. You may want to look at it. A lot of the answers posted to your question are already on this existing question plus more.

Answer (score 3):

Rob Conery's StoreFront application includes an excellent walk-through so you can build the project with him from scratch.  I highly recommend it for learning MVC

http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/

Answer (score 2):

[Oxite](http://oxite.codeplex.com/)

Comment: +1. A bit odd this has no upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

**[KiGG](http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg)**, a Digg clone, has been updated to ASP.NET MVC 1.0 RTM.

[image]

Some features it includes:

**Microsoft Tooling:**

- ASP.NET MVC
- Linq To SQL
- MS Patterns & Practices – Enterprise Library (Logging & Caching)
- MS Patterns & Practices - Unity
- jQuery

**Other Third party:**

- xUnit.net
- Moq
- HtmlAgilityPack
- DotNetOpenId
- jQuery UI & Markitup

**External Service Integration:**

- PageGlimpse, WebSnapr - For thumbnail generation.
- Akismet, TypePad and Defensio. - Spam Protection.
- reCaptcha
- Gravatar
- OpenID & Id Selector
- Url shrinking services (http://tinyurl.com & http://is.gd)

**Open Standard implementation:**

- hAtom, hReview, hVote, xFolk etc.
- OpenSearch
- SiteMap (Standard, Mobile, News)
- RSS/Atom

There are several live websites using the MVC KiGG demo as the base for their website:

- [DotNetShoutout.com](http://dotnetshoutout.com/)
- [progg.ru](http://progg.ru/)
- [dotnetomaniak](http://dotnetomaniak.pl/)
- [PimpThisBlog](http://www.pimpthisblog.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft also release a resource kit for developing web 2.0 apps called Kobe. It has a sample asp.net mvc app in it.

Comment: It's been pulled temporarily because of adverse publicity