# ASP.net MVC Linq-To-SQL Many-To-Many Field Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, model-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modeling a many-to-many relationship in ASP.NET MVC using LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145034/modeling-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-asp-net-mvc-using-linq-to-sql)

Hi there,

The short version of this question is "Is there a way to gracefully handle database insertion for an object that has a many-to-many field that has been set up in a partial class?"  Apologies if it's been asked before.
**Example**
Suppose I have a typical MVC setup with the tables:

> - Posts {PostID, ...}
> - Categories {CategoryID, ...}

A post can have more than one category, and a category can identify more than one post.  Thus suppose further that I need an extra table:

> - PostCategories {PostID, CategoryID, ...}

This handles the many-to-many relationship between posts and categories.  As far as I know, there's no way to do this in Linq-to-SQL right now so I have to shoehorn it in by adding a partial Post class to the project to add that functionality.  Something like:

```
public partial class Post
{
   public IEnumerable<Category> Categories{ get { ... } set { ... } }
}
```

So I can now create a "Create" view that automatically populates a "Categories" UI item.  It even handles like any other field- fun!

This is where the trouble starts.

**So here's my question:**
How do you get automatic object model binding to work cleanly with an object that has a many-to-many relationship to control?  The workaround that makes many-to-many relationships possible relies on the Post object having a PostID in order to be associated with CategoryID(s), which is only issued *after* the Post object has been submitted for validation and insertion.

Bit of a Catch22 here.  Any terminology, links, or tips you can provide would be tremendously helpful!